# javascript go to url with unicode characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, unicode

I have an array with some urls like these:

```
[
  "path/to/url1",
  "path/to/url2",
  "path/url/unicóde.txt"
]
```

I'm using angular, with `ng-repeat` I created a clickable list that perform a redirect to desired url, but, when I clicked unicode url, the browser cant find it.

I try with `encodeURI("path/url/unicóde")`, but it retrieves this:
`path/url/unic%C3%B3de.txt` which is not found. Instead, when I accessing manually to: `path/url/unicóde.txt` (this is in an ftp, so, I go folder by folder until arrive to the file) the url in the browser now says: `path/url/unic%F3de.txt`, which is different to value that gave me `encodeURI( )`.

How then I can clic to this list item and to be redirected to desired unicode url?

Here the code:
html:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="found in foundFiles">
        <h3>{{ found.name }}</h3>
        <p ng-click="openFtpLink(found.url)">{{ found.url}}</p>
    </md-list-item>
```

javascript:

```
$scope.foundFiles = [...]
$scope.openFtpLink = function (ftpLink) {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'start', '', ftpLink]);
};
```

This is an app build with electron + angular, what I want here is that when user clicks the item, open his default browser and redirect it to url

Comment: Try adding `charset="utf-8"` to your script tag.

Comment: "I created a clickable list that perform a redirect to desired url" - need to see code for this, as you seem to be doing something wrong regarding URL decoding (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript `escape()` Function. It gives you desired output.

```js
alert(escape("path/url/unicóde.txt"));
```

Note : The `escape()` function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5.

Comment: escape() is deprecated, like you say, and should be replaced with encodeURI(), but, in this case, it works, and encodeURI() does not. thanks for your answer!